# Ping Servers with Javascript, passively from server, not from a visitors DOM

Tags: javascript

I want to run a script from my server that pings other sites.

I came accross this fiddle that does it well: http://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/

The only problem is for my functionality I don't need the DOM to load the page or anything to ping.  I want to run it passively from the server.

I can't exactly load this into the header of my screen and call it onLoad.  Then the servers will only get pinged when someone loads the page.  I want them to be pinging the servers regardless of whether or not someone is loading the page.

How could I achieve this?  Would I need to be using Node-JS?

Here the function (if you don't wanna click the fiddle)

```
function ping(ip, callback) {

    if (!this.inUse) {
        this.status = 'unchecked';
        this.inUse = true;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.ip = ip;
        var _that = this;
        this.img = new Image();
        this.img.onload = function () {
            _that.inUse = false;
            _that.callback('responded');

        };
        this.img.onerror = function (e) {
            if (_that.inUse) {
                _that.inUse = false;
                _that.callback('responded', e);
            }

        };
        this.start = new Date().getTime();
        this.img.src = "http://" + ip;
        this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            if (_that.inUse) {
                _that.inUse = false;
                _that.callback('timeout');
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
}
var PingModel = function (servers) {
    var self = this;
    var myServers = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(servers, function (location) {
        myServers.push({
            name: location,
            status: ko.observable('unchecked')
        });
    });
    self.servers = ko.observableArray(myServers);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.servers(), function (s) {
        s.status('checking');
        new ping(s.name, function (status, e) {
            s.status(status);
        });
    });
};
var komodel = new PingModel(['localhost',
    'ws-bdimperio8',
    'ws-bdimperio8.payformance.net',
    'ws-bdimperio8.payformance.com',
    'ws-bdimperio8.payspan.com',
    'ws-bdimperio8/favicon.ico',
    '127.0.0.1', 
    'unknown'
    ]);
ko.applyBindings(komodel);
```

Thanks

Comment: Run a `cron` job on the server that updates a database, and then provide a web page that displays the results from the database.

Comment: This site doesn't have a DB, is there a way to do it without DB interaction?

Comment: Sure - write the result to something other than a database.

Comment: Go old school: http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/mrtg.en.html

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear.  I don't really care about the results. I just want to ping site X Y and Z so they don't fall asleep.  I have a script that achieves this, but only when I load page P.  I want it to run all the time from the server, not from page loads.  How would writing to a file change this?